# how to read the content of any attached file in php

Tags: php, mysql

How can I read the data from file if data is like this.

`<area shape="poly" alt="1101" coords="1735,606, 1736,606, 1737,606, 1738,606, 1739,606, 1740,606, 1741,607,`

I know how to open the file and how to read and store the data simply but how can I extract the data from "alt" and "coords" please help me out.

```
<?php
    $handle = @fopen("sunset_map.map", "r");
    $conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); 
    mysql_select_db("read_data",$conn);
    while (!feof($handle)) // Loop til end of file.
    {

    $buffer = fgets($handle, 4096);
    // Read a line.
    // $a = $_get['alt']  ;
    // $b = $_get['coords'];
    // parse_str("alt = str& coords = ",$myarray);
    // print_r($myarray);
    list($a,$b)=explode("|",$buffer);
    // list($myarray)=explode("|",$buffer);
    //Separate string by the means of |
    // echo $a."-".$b."<br>";
    $sql = "INSERT INTO content_data (id,coords) VALUES('".$a."','".$b."')";   
    mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());

    }
?>
```

Comment: Your example of the contents of the .map file is incomplete, so it is hard to answer.  Is it multiple `<area>` tags?

Comment: if have a large data which have many <area > tag which contains different "alt" and "coords" having diffrent value and i want to extract the value from alt and coords and store it in my data base the above is only eg that i have been shown to you.

Comment: <area shape="poly" alt="1102" coords="1790,655, 1791,655, 1792,655, 1793,656, 1794,657, 1794,658, 1795,659, 1796,660, 1797,661, 1798,662, 1798,663, 1799,664, 1800,665, 1801,666, 1802,667, 1802,668, 1803,669, 1804,670, 1805,671, 1806,672, 1806,673, 1807,674, 1808,675, 1809,676, 1810,677, 1810,678,
1811,679, 1812,680, 1813,681, 1789,656" href="#"> Supppose it is like that.

Comment: Presumably the `alt` attribute is the bit containing the `id` for your SQL?  If the file only contains these area tags and nothing else, then the regex answer by Marian Bida is simplest, with a bit of work.  Otherwise you may need to parse the document as described in the other answers.

Comment: i think i display the question in wrong manner. actually i want to extract data from substring which is stored in a file as i mention in eg. so i want store it in databasre so how can i do this?

Comment: my file is .map file and it has some data like this Eg:<area shape = "poly" alt="1101" coords="1735,606, 1736,606, 1737,606, 1738,606, 1739,606, 1740,606, 1741,607, 1742,607, 1743,607, 1744,607, 694, 1740,695>  i want to extract only the values of "alt" and "coords"  and store it in database so how can i do this  there are more than thousand of records in my file so can i do this please help me out.

Comment: Is there anything else in the file - or just `<area>` tags?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to parse the HTML. Get the area elements by using [DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php). Then, as you're looping through those elements, you can use [DOMElement::getAttribute](http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php) to get the "alt" and "coords" attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Use regex:

```
$text = '<area shape="poly" alt="1101" coords="1735,606, 1736,606, 1737,606, 1738,606, 1739,606, 1740,606, 1741,607" />';
if (preg_match("/area shape=\"poly\" alt=\"(.*)\" coords=\"(.*)\" /sUSi", $text, $data) {
echo $data[0] . ' ' . $data[1] . ' ' . $data[2];
}
```

Comment: sorry i don't understand your answer may be i interpret the question in wrong way so please help me. m again display 1 eg for you my file is .map file and it has some data like this Eg:<area shape = "poly" alt="1101" coords="1735,606, 1736,606, 1737,606, 1738,606, 1739,606, 1740,606, 1741,607, 1742,607, 1743,607, 1744,607, 694, 1740,695>  i want to extract only the values of "alt" and "coords"  and store it in database so how can i do this  there are more than thousand of records in my file so can i do this please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the file is XML data. If so, use the XMLReader interface to get the area nodes something like this:

```
$sb = new XMLReader;
$sb->open( "sunset_map.map" );
if( $sb === FALSE ) {
    print "Error: Can't open the file. Aborting.\n";
    exit(1);
}

    // find the first area element
    while( $sb->read() && $sb->name !== 'area' )
      ;

    while( $sb->name == 'area' ) {
       // get the attributes you need
       $coords = $sb->getAttribute('coords');
       // Now split the $coords string with explode and whatever
       // and do your inserts

       $sb->next('area');
    }
```